# How to restore a GL_RENDERBUFFER?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer, opengl-es-3.0

I am working on storing and restoring my OpenGL ES based application's state.

I have a function to save the GL_RENDERBUFFER to dump the data with the following code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.colorbuffer);

GLint x = 0, y = 0, width2 = backingWidth, height2 = backingHeight;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

I don't see a glWritePixels function. What is the best way to repopulate the GL_RENDERBUFFER with the GLubyte data populated above? An example would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 3:

Here is how I am attempting to configure the texture render buffer, and the function used to draw it. As noted in the code, if I specify GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 for the glFramebufferTexture2D parameter, the stored pixel data is restored but I can't get any updates to draw. But if I use GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 instead, I get drawing updates but no pixel data restored.

I have tried various combinations (for instance also using GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 for the glFramebufferRenderbuffer parameter) but then I get an invalid frame buffer error when attempting to render. It seems I am so close, but can't figure out how to get them both restoring and rendering working together.

```
- (bool)configureRenderTextureBuffer {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &fboTextureBufferData.colorbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.colorbuffer);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.colorbuffer);

    // Generate texture name, stores in .textureID
    glGenTextures(1, &fboTextureBufferData.textureID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureBufferData.textureID);

    ////////////////// Read Existing texture data //////////////////
    NSString *dataPath = [TDTDeviceUtilitesLegacy documentDirectory]; //This just returns the app's document directory
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/buffer.data", dataPath]];
    GLubyte *pixelData = (GLubyte*)[data bytes];

    // If I use GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 here, my existing pixel data is restored
    // but no drawing occurs. If I use GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, then data isn't
    // restored but drawing updates work
    glFramebufferTexture2D ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureBufferData.textureID, 0 );

    // Populate with existing data
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, backingWidth, backingHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelData[0]); //&image[0]

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete render texture framebuffer object %x", status);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the code for rendering. The viewFramebuffer is attached to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and is used so the texture frame buffer can be zoomed and positioned inside the view.

```
- (void)renderTextureBuffer {

    //Bind the texture frame buffer, if I don't use this, I can't get it to draw
    //glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer);

    //If I use this instead of binding the framebuffer above, I get no drawing and black background
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureBufferData.textureID, 0);

    renderParticlesToTextureBuffer();

    //Bind the view frame buffer.
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

    drawFboTexture();

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Comment: Probably easier to use a texture instead of a renderbuffer. Then you can use `glTexImage2D()` to fill it with data.

Comment: Problem with that approach, is I think it would take much more memory. It would be a rather large texture - around 67MB (4096x4096x4), whereas the render buffer is already allocated.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a texture *instead of* a renderbuffer. So never allocate a renderbuffer in the first place, and use a texture in its place.

Comment: But I need a render buffer.

Comment: To clarify, its a drawing application, so I need a render buffer to accumulate the brush strokes per frame.

Comment: You can use a texture as a FBO attachment, and render to it just like you render to a renderbuffer.

Comment: Interesting. Could you point me to an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to write data directly to a render target, using a renderbuffer is not a good option. In this case, it's much better to use a texture instead.

Using a texture as a FBO attachment works very similarly to using a renderbuffer. Where you currently use `glRenderbufferStorage()` to allocate a renderbuffer of the needed dimensions, you create a texture instead, and allocate its storage with:

```
GLuint texId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 0);
```

Then you attach it to the framebuffer with:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);
```

Now, if you later want to fill your render target with data, you can simply call `glTexImage2D()` again, or even better `glTexSubImage2D()` if the size is unchanged, to do that.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to implement this now. Currently before drawing to the framebuffer, I am binding it with: `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer);` Since the frame buffer isn't generated, the pointer for `fboTextureBufferData.framebuffer` doesn't exist. So how I do bind the texture for rendering? Note that I have a 2nd frame buffer, so binding at runtime is required.

Comment: Just use `glFramebufferTexture2d` instead of `glFramebufferRenderbuffer`.

Comment: I can't get anything to draw with this. Can you please look at my edit above and look at how I am initializing and drawing?

Comment: It's not clear how to restore the texture still. Do I provide my populated "data" variable (from my sample code above) for the `glTexSubImage2D` "pixels" argument? Also note, according to Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html), the `glTexImage2D` and `glFramebufferTexture2D` calls are required *in addition* to generating a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, so that part of my code might be right.

Comment: @Reto Koradi can you please see edit 3 above? I can get it to draw restored pixels or fresh rendered pixels, but not both together. I'm really stumped!